# how to get file path in textbox using windows form application?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have one browse button and one text box. In the browse_button click event, I would like to browse the files and place the path name into textbox. For this I've written code like this by using openfile dialog.

```
private void brwsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                  textBox1.Text = openFD.FileName;
            }
            textBox1.Text="";
        }
```

So that I am able to select files only. How can I select and place the folders path in textbox?.

In my application the user should able to select either file or folder through a single browse button. Please suggest me how to write code for this.

Note. Please let me know can we use to upload file without using Openfiledialog in windows form..

Comment: OpenFileDialog is for selecting files, not folders. If you need to select a Folder then there is the FolderBrowserDialog

Comment: Here i am using excel file only. i am able to select files only but i cant place the folders path in textbox. while clicking the upload button in win form

Comment: You must use 2 button, one for brow file, one for folder. With the file dialog if you want extract the folder path it is easy.

Comment: I want to extract file path alone in text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code don't add file path to the text box because you have this line:

```
textBox1.Text = "";
```

Which auto clear the line:

```
textBox1.Text = openFD.FileName;
```

Remove it and you can add file path to textbox:

```
private void brwsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = openFD.FileName;
    }
}
```

If you want file name only (not include path), you can use:

```
private void brwsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Path.GetFileName(openFD.FileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a FolderBrowserDialog to your form. Then something like this will work:

```
if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
   }
```

You can also use your existing fileDialog to do

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(openFD.FileName);
```

Comment: hello i have to get file path only in texbox not folder path. please kindly guide me

Comment: Yes so using your existing code just try this `Path.GetDirectoryName(openFD.FileName);` or replace your line `textBox1.Text = openFD.FileName;` with: `textBox1.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFD.FileName);` also add Using System.IO for usage of Path.